# image distortion issue in jCrop

Tags: jquery, jcrop

[image: iamge distorion]

the html srouce code:
[image]

That's rellay strange. I call the jCrop function when the image is loaded, I'm sure jCrop can get the real width and height of the image, but the resut is the image is distorted.

Is there anyone encounter this error?

Comment: Are you using a custom width and height on the original image? Also, we need to see your html and javascript. If they're large, use https://gist.github.com/

Comment: @Computer Linguist, I finally found the key point, the img tag was set "max-width:100%" in my css. I delete it, then everything comes right.

Answer (score 3):

> I finally found the key point, the img tag was set "max-width:100%" in my css. I delete it, then everything comes right

Comment: This doesn't help if your app is responsive. max-width: 100% is how all dynamic width images should be in that case. Wondering if that kills Jcrop in those cases...

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but there is a fix for this in the works. It was a selector bug. You can get the branch with the fix here (it hasn't been officially released)

https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/pull/75

Comment: If your app is responsive, you need the max-width: 100%. All this fix does it override that. Not really a fix in my opinion.