# jCrop with preview relative to actual crop

Tags: javascript, jcrop

I'm using jCorp with an image preview from code I found here: [www.deepliquid.com](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=handler) . I don't really need the image preview but it's a nice touch! The problem is when I "turn off" aspect ratio I get a distorted image in the preview pain, that said it crops just fine as shown below.

**Cropping page with Preview:**

[image]
**Cropped Image**

[image]

Has anyone come up with an amazing javascript way of making this happen? Javascript is not my forte!

Comment: Has anyone done this or can it not be done with JS???

Comment: possible duplicate of [image distortion issue in jCrop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427567/image-distortion-issue-in-jcrop)